# PDF generation with TCPDF in Yii2

Tags: php, pdf, yii2, tcpdf

I installed these packages: "hbalkhi/yii2-pdf": "dev-master" and "setasign/fpdi-tcpdf": "1.6.2". And now I am trying to generate example pdf file as it is shown here:
https://packagist.org/packages/hbalkhi/yii2-pdf

Unfortunately, all I was able to get looks like: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytTO9.png)
How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

`Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_RAW;
Yii::$app->response->headers->add('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
return $this->render('tcpdf');`